# I need to find the last booked date in a list of dates, but my code returns blanks where there are dates

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

The macro searches the first column in a worksheet for the last row with a date. I've tried different formats for the date which hasn't helped. I have about 15 dates in the list.

I've tried formatting as dates and numbers with different tests, but it always gives an incorrect result.

This version returns the second row as '0' even though it has a valid date in it, which then gives the wrong result.

```
Function FindLastRow()                           ' Find last booking and record the row

    Dim BookDate As Double
    
    For BookingRow = 4 To 100                         ' Start assuming no more than 100 bookings
        BookDate = Cells(BookingRow, 1).Value
        If BookDate <> 0 Then             ' If row is not blank
            Debug.Print BookDate, BookingRow
                                          
        Else
            Debug.Print BookDate, BookingRow
            Last = BookingRow - 1                              ' this row must be last entry
            Exit For
        End If
    Next BookingRow
    FindLastRow = Last
    
End Function
```

Comment: `If IsDate(BookDate) Then`

Comment: The first row returns a date value no problem, the second row doesn't even though there's a date in it. The date column contains 27/12/2021 in the first row, 29/01/2022 in the second and the whole column if formatted as date. This seems to be the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, the BookDate is retrieve with the Cells function.  I Believe the method ".Value" is required for Range() function but not for Cells() function.

Comment: I tried your code, and I was not able to reproduce the problem as you mentioned.  I filled row 1 to 19 with date and the function returns the last row as 19. It works the same with data type as Double or Date. 
When you mentioned that the second row was returned as "0", Did you mean row 5 as the function search from row 4 to 100?

Comment: The function return the last row, however the Debug.Print function print the last empty row.

Comment: Yes, it returns row 5 as it seems to not have a date in it.